# Optimised visualisation of top circles in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, header-footer, themes, mini-frames

I am making a presentation in `Beamer`. I am using `smoothbars` as an outer theme. However I am having a problem when a `section` has many frames, as indicated in the following image

[image]

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\mode<presentation>
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[SRS/APV readout with mmDAQ/Recomm\hspace{1.5cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{rd51 mm     tracker \& SRS/APV readout using mmDAQ/Recomm}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]    {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
%------------------tikz------------------------

\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I only included the `titlepage` just to have an output. If you want me I can add some more plots as `sections` in order to achieve many circles.

A way to fix this is to change `section`'s name so as to fit more circles, but I think it's not the best. Is there another way to do it, without changing inner theme's height?

Comment: The mini frames (that's what these little circles are called) are controlled by the outer theme, so in order to help you, we'll have to know what you specified using `\useoutertheme`. Please provide a [complete minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that produces the overflowing mini frames as shown in your screenshot.

Comment: I will do it asap!!!

Comment: What version of beamer do you have? With my `beamer.cls`from  2011/09/12 the [output looks good](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vP0Ya.png). (Also `slidestop` is replaced by `t` and TikZ annoys me that the snakes library is superseded by decorations …) Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: All I can tell is that I am running `MikTex 2.8.3759`. I typed `beamer -version` on a command prompt but I cannot find out. Isn't there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Thanos Try updating MiKTeX as described [in the manual](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/updating.html). Even better, [download and install](http://miktex.org/download) the latest version `2.9`.