# Modify Beamer's outer theme smoothbars

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes, mini-frames

I am making a beamer presentation with XeTeX, in which I am using `Ilmenau` theme. This theme has by default `smoothbars` as an outer theme. My problem that in a section's subsection, there are a lot of frames, which makes too many bullets in the header. How Can I remove/wrap those bullets from header to make the presentation look a bit more pretty.

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
%\setromanfont{GFS Neohellenic}
\mode<presentation>
\AtBeginSection[]
{
 \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \footnotesize{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
  \end{frame}
}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
%\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\begin{document}

\section{Results}

\subsection{First Subsection}
\frame{Frame 0}

\subsection{Long Subsection}
\frame{Frame 1}
\frame{Frame 2}
\frame{Frame 3}
\frame{Frame 4}
\frame{Frame 5}
\frame{Frame 6}

\subsection{Third Subsection}
\frame{Frame 7}

\end{document}
```

My ugly output is

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex StackExchange!

Comment: I was facing the same problem once(http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74846/optimised-visualisation-of-top-circles-in-beamer) and I was adviced to update/upgrade my MikTeX distribution. Which distro are you using?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve here: I don't see any overflow problems in your output, it's simply one bullet (they are called mini frames, BTW) for each slide of the subsection. Maybe you want [only one mini frame per subsection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64333/3323)?

Comment: @diabonas: Thank you very much for your citation! That was exactly what I needed! Instead of a comment, is it possible to add an answer in order to accept it?

Comment: @Thanos: I am using TeXlive on ubuntu 11.04...

Answer (score 4):

As a possible solution, you could consider to use the subsection title instead
of a bullet for each frame. If this is prettier than the bullets is a matter of
personal taste :). Here is what I've got:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Frames 1 to 6 highlight the *Longest subsection* title. The trick is to use the
`\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal` and
`\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal` instead of the `\insertnavigation` used by the mini frames theme. The only modification to your code is
the definition of the `headline` beamer template. The code is adapted from the
Mini frames outer theme that is what Ilmenau theme uses by default.

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}\vskip2pt
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=10pt]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \vskip2pt\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}\vskip2pt
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Add this code after loading the Ilmenau theme, and before the
`\begin{document}`. The `\hskip0pt plus1filll` is used to left-justify the
section and subsection titles.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that I actually want the bullet points to show up... diabonas provides a comment which links to a probable accepted solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64333/one-navigation-bullet-per-subsection-with-subsection-false-in-custom-beamer-them