# LaTeX Beamer style

Tags: beamer

I never used `beamer` in LaTeX, could anyone suggest how can i get the output using `beamer`, it will helpful for to proceed my project?

[image: Beamer style]

Comment: Maybe you find it here: http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

Comment: Here the same theme and structure: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97731/modify-beamers-outer-theme-smoothbars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme looks like a combination of `smoothbars` and `miniframes`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\author{names}
\title{text}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sam thanks for answer when i used the same coding as you mentioned but the white dot below "Introduction" not comes in my output. Could you please help how to achieve this output.

Comment: @RajeshKumar Did you compile two times?